# Allow Discord Rewrite bot to respond to other bots

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a Discord bot and a webhook setup for a Discord channel to send a command every hour on the dot. However it seems that Discord Rewrite by default ignores commands sent from other bots. How do I go about disabling this?

Do I need to modify something on a per-command function or the `on_message` function?

Current `on_message`:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Rather than editing you original question I would recommend posting your solution as a answer. This is a common accepted way to do this on stackoverflow. :)

Comment: I don't recommend responding to other bots, if you did, you can't apply your bot in top.gg.

Comment: By default, your bot will respond to other bots's messages. I'm not sure about commands, but it does responds to messages

Edit:  What is it that you exactly want? Other bots to respond to your bot? or your bot to respond to other bots?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a check for it:

on_message:

```
if message.author.bot == True:
    #Do something
```

command:

```
if ctx.author.bot == True:
    #Do something
```

Comment: you should use `is` instead of `==`. in this case, the `== True` can be omitted since the value of `User.bot` is always either True or False

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    ctx = await bot.get_context(message)
    await bot.invoke(ctx)
```

as per OP @Cynthia Valdez's edit to the question.