# Allow bot commands (only for testing)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pytest

I would like to create a simple smoke test for my application using pytest. It would be really simple for me, that's why I tried. The problem is that bots does not reacts for other bot's message as I noticed. I looked at the code (bot.py) and modified the process_commands just for the smoke test. Unfortunately it's still works only for human messages during testing.

Edited code, a complete test (only HASH and channel id are imported)

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import pytest
import threading
import time

from build_config import HASH, channel_id


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.', description="This is a test bot for stackoverflow!")


class Test_Message(commands.Cog):
    @commands.command(pass_context = True)
    async def message(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("text_message")


def run_bot():
    bot.add_cog(Test_Message())
    bot.run(HASH.DEBUG)


@pytest.fixture
def create_bot():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=run_bot, args=[])
    t1.start()


class Test_Events:
    successful = False

    @staticmethod
    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
        await channel.send('.message')

    @staticmethod
    @bot.event
    async def on_message(message):
        await bot.process_commands(message)
        if (message.channel.name == "general" and message.clean_content == "text_message"):
            Test_Events.successful = True

    @staticmethod
    @bot.event
    async def process_commands(message):
        ctx = await bot.get_context(message)
        await bot.invoke(ctx)


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_Smoke(create_bot):
    must_end = time.time() + 60
    while time.time() < must_end:
        if Test_Events.successful:
            break
        time.sleep(1)
    assert Test_Events.successful
```

Basically someone marked this one as a solution in [Allow Discord Rewrite bot to respond to other bots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55318704/allow-discord-rewrite-bot-to-respond-to-other-bots), but it doesn’t work for me.

Edit: So I debug the discord.py, unfortunately there is at least another check in `get_context self._skip_check(message.author.id, self.user.id)`.

Comment: Did you pay attention to proper indentation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Properly indented code and it works for user commands.

Comment: Your events don't look like proper indentation to me. As I understand it, these don't work?

Comment: Nope. You don't understand and that's how you indent a .bot.event. The code above works if a human discord user writes ```.send_expected``` (which is a command in Event) during test, but not if the command is written only by the bot at on_ready (```await Print.message_to_channel("bot", ".send_expected")```)

Comment: How are you passing these functions?  If these are really object methods, then all three of those need a "self" parameter.  If these are being called as class static methods (Test_Events.on_ready), then they wouldn't.

Comment: The @MyClient.bot.event is a decorator that register this function. Of course it should be @staticmethod, but it doesn't change much (but I changed it). Even though I overwrote the ```process_commands```, the bot does not accept commands from other bots. If I submit the command manually from my discord account during the test, the bot accepts it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out that the creators of discord.py created an overwritable `process_commands` function. That's why you can remove the

```py
if message.author.bot:
    return
```

part. Unfortunately this is not enough for anything, there is such a part deep in the code which reject the bot commands:

```py
if self._skip_check(message.author.id, self.user.id):
    return ctx
```

The solution is to take this check out:

```py
bot._skip_check = lambda x, y: False
```

**I only use this workaround for testing, it is forbidden to use anything like this one on a normal server.**